# SVN - tag only the project with its modules

Tags: maven, svn, maven-3, release, maven-release-plugin

I have a SVN repository with this Maven projects at trunk level:

- model (jar packaging)
- core (jar packaging)
- dao.mysql (jar packaging)
- dao.oracle (jar packaging)
- executable.mysql (pom packaging, with 3 modules: model, core, dao.mysql)
- executable.oracle (pom packaging, with 3 modules: model, core, dao.oracle)

When I generate SVN tags with maven-release-plugin, release:prepare goal, for project executable.oracle, all the projects in the repository are versioned in the tag.

In the example above, I only want executable.oracle and its three dependencies/modules were tagged.

It is possible or am I misunderstading any concept? Any way to configure it?

Any help is very appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: I assume you are having a multi module build where the parent pom.xml which is at the trunk level of your svn repository contains a list of `<module>...</module>`? If so than this is a multi module build which means the whole will be handled as artifacts which will be released together which is the purpose of a multi module build. If you like to release parts of it separately you have to separate those modules into separate projects and into different svn locations...

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks a lot for your answer. I have edited the post to specify all the projects are at trunk level. About your answer, I understand a tag copies all the projects, so, if I'd want to separate in two SVN repositories (one for MySQL and one for Oracle), should model and core components be copied in each repository? And should they be maintained the same sources twice? Thanks again